# Написание собственного фильтра для диапазона

Tags: c++, range, c++20

Пытаюсь разобраться, как работать с диапазонами в С++20 по книге Rainer Grimm "C++20 Get the details".

Хочу написать собственный фильтр, которому бы можно было передать контейнер (пусть просто вектор) и который бы отфильтрованные элементы выводил бы в него и передавал дальше. Чтоб пожно было написать что-то вроде

```
vect | views::filter(f1) | views::transform(f2) | copy_to(w) | views::filter(f3)
```

примерно так. Т.е. после фильтрации и преобразования скидываем в вектор `w` и фильтруем себе дальше.

Только вот совершенно запутался, как сделать такую вещь. Если я правильно понимаю, то должны быть только `begin()` и `end()` для диапазона. Так? А как получить очередной элемент и записать его?

Если где-то есть более ПРОСТОЕ описание написания фильтров (да и самих диапазонов... никак не могу их понять, как оно там внутри) - буду рад услышать.

Свой позор привожу *исключительно* для того, чтоб вопрос не закрыли из-за отсутствия собственных попыток. Потому что это в стиле "лишь бы компилировалось" из-за полного непонимания, как это должно работать...

```
using namespace std::ranges;

template<typename Container, std::ranges::input_range Range> requires std::ranges::view<Range>
class copy_to : public std::ranges::view_interface<copy_to<Container,Range>>
{
private:
    Container * c = nullptr;
    Range range_{};
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Range> begin_{ std::begin(range_) };
    std::ranges::iterator_t<Range> end_{ std::end(range_) };

public:
    //Container() = default;

    constexpr copy_to(Container& c, Range r): c(&c), range_(std::move(r)),
    begin_(std::begin(r)), end_(std::end(r))
    {
        for(auto b = begin_; b != end_; ++b) c->push_back(*b);
    }

    constexpr copy_to(Container& c): c(&c), begin_(std::begin(c)), end_(std::end(c))
    {
        for(auto b = begin_; b != end_; ++b) c->push_back(*b);
    }

    constexpr auto begin() const {
        return begin_;
    }
    constexpr auto end() const {
        return end_;
    }
};

template<typename Container, typename Range>
copy_to(Container&, Range&&) -> copy_to<Container, std::ranges::views::all_t<Range>>;
```

Comment: Как написать представление, не подскажу... но как выкрутиться для конкретной задачи — запросто: `vector<int> v{1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8}; vector<int> w; for(auto i : v | views::reverse | views::transform([&w](int i){w.push_back(i); return i;}) | views::take(6)) cout << i << " ";`

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, это решает конкретную задачу, но не учит решать задачу написания views в общем случае

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы пишите свою операцию для работы с диапазонами, то вы имеете дело с тремя типами: (1) - результат выполнения `copy_to(w)` - это может быть собственно тип `copy_to`. Этот тип не обязан выглядеть как диапазон или контейнер. (2) - результат выполнения `...|copy_to(w)` - это уже другой тип. И он, как раз, обязан быть контейнером или диапазоном. (3) - результат выполнения `...|copy_to(w)|...` - это уже забота операнда справа, если только мы не переопределим оператор | (справо), например, для оптимизации.

Шаблон `std::ranges::view_interface` предназначен для определения собственных диапазонов, т.е. он может подойти для типа (2), но ненужен для (1). Вы попытались соединить в одном типы (1) и (2).

Пример решения:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::ranges;


template<typename Container>
class copy_to
{
    Container& output;
public:
    copy_to(Container& output) : output(output) {}
    copy_to(const copy_to&) = default;
    copy_to(copy_to&&) = default;
    
    
    template<viewable_range Range>
    friend auto operator | ( Range range, const copy_to& output )
    {
        auto& w = output.output;
        for( auto i : range )
            w.push_back( i );
        return range;
    }
};
template<typename Container>
copy_to(Container&) -> copy_to<Container>;


int main()
{
    auto f1=[](int i){ return i%3!=0; };
    auto f2=[](int i){ return i+2; };
    auto f3=[](int i){ return i*3; };
    
    std::vector<int> vect = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> w;
    for( int i :  vect | views::filter(f1) | views::transform(f2) | copy_to(w) | views::transform(f3) )
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    for( int i : w )
        std::cout<<i<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее, но все равно надо думать ))